Row based filter and aggregation in pandas python
I have two dataframes as below.
df1:
data1 = {
    'Acc': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'indi_val': ['Val1', 'val2', 'Val_E', 'Val1_E', 'Val1', 'Val3', 'val2', 'val2_E', 'val22_E', 'val2_A', 'val2_V', 'Val_E', 'Val_A', 'Val', 'Val2', 'val7'],
    'Amt': [10, 20, 5, 5, 22, 38, 15, 25, 22, 23, 24, 56, 67, 45, 87, 88]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df2:
data2 = {
    'Acc': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    'Indi': ['With E', 'Without E', 'With E', 'Without E', 'Normal', 'Normal']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

Based on these two dataframes I need to create final output as below:
 AccNo  Indi        Amt
 1      With E      7
 1      Without E   90
 2      With E      47
 2      Without E   62
 3      Normal      225
 4      Normal      88

The logic:

with E: where last 2 characters from df1['indi_val] equal "_E", get sum(Amt).
Without E: where last 2 characters from df1['indi_val'] do not equal "_E", get sum(Amt).
Normal: without any filter on df1['indi_val'], get sum(Amt).

I tried writing something as below:
def get_indi(row):
    listval = []
    if row['Indi'] == "With E":
        #print('A')
        df1.apply(lambda df1row: listval.append(df1row['amt'] if df1row['Acc']==row['Acc'] and df1row['indi_val'][-2:]=="_E" else 0))
    
    if row['Indi'] == "Without E":
        df1.apply(lambda df1row: listval.append(df1row['amt'] if df1row['Acc']==row['Acc'] and df1row['indi_val'][-2:]!="_E" else 0))
    
    if row['Indi'] == "Normal":
        df1.apply(lambda df1row: listval.append(df1row['amt']))
        
    return sum(listval)

# Apply the function to create the 'Indi' column in df1
df2['Amt'] = df2.apply(get_indi)

With above code I am getting the following error:
get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Indi'


Your expected output doesn't add up...

Code
import numpy as np
cond = df1['indi_val'].str.contains('_E')
grp = np.where(cond, 'With E', 'Without E')
tmp = (df1.groupby(['Acc', grp])['Amt'].sum()
          .reset_index().rename({'level_1': 'Indi'}, axis=1)
)

tmp:
     Acc   Indi     Amt
0    1     With E   10
1    1  Without E   90
2    2     With E   47
3    2  Without E   62
4    3     With E   56
5    3  Without E  199
6    4  Without E   88


out = df2.merge(
    pd.concat([tmp, tmp.groupby('Acc')['Amt'].sum().reset_index().assign(Indi='Normal')]), 
    how='left'
)

out
     Acc   Indi     Amt
0    1     With E   10
1    1  Without E   90
2    2     With E   47
3    2  Without E   62
4    3     Normal  255
5    4     Normal   88


Firstly, apply might not be the best approach here, but for your use-case you need to explicitly mention axis=1 for all your apply calls like this:
df2.apply(get_indi, axis=1)

A better solution would be to use pandas group by and aggregate followed by merge operations:
df_temp = []
# normal
qwe = df1.groupby('Acc')['Amt'].sum().reset_index()
qwe['Indi'] = 'Normal'
df_temp.append(qwe)
# With E
qwe = df1[df1['indi_val'].str.endswith('_E')].groupby('Acc')['Amt'].sum().reset_index()
qwe['Indi'] = 'With E'
df_temp.append(qwe)
# Without E
qwe = df1[~df1['indi_val'].str.endswith('_E')].groupby('Acc')['Amt'].sum().reset_index()
qwe['Indi'] = 'Without E'
df_temp.append(qwe)

df_temp = pd.concat(df_temp)
# merge
df2.merge(df_temp, on=['Acc', 'Indi'])


Output:




Acc
Indi
Amt




0
1
With E
10


1
1
Without E
90


2
2
With E
47


3
2
Without E
62


4
3
Normal
255


5
4
Normal
88




Here's one approach:
import numpy as np # add import

out = (
    df2
    .merge(df1, on='Acc', how='left')
    .pipe(lambda x: x[
        (
            (
                np.where(x['indi_val'].str.endswith('_E'), 'With E', 'Without E') == 
                x['Indi']
             ) | 
            x['Indi'].eq('Normal')
        )
    ])
    .groupby(['Acc', 'Indi'], as_index=False)['Amt'].sum()
)

Output
   Acc       Indi  Amt
0    1     With E   10
1    1  Without E   90
2    2     With E   47
3    2  Without E   62
4    3     Normal  255
5    4     Normal   88

Explanation

Left merge df2 with df1 on column 'Acc' (df.merge).
Use df.pipe to work with the merged result (now: x) and create a condition to apply boolean indexing.

Check if x['indi_val'] ends with '_E' (Series.str.endswith), and use np.where to get the suitable description for each row, namely 'With E' or 'Without E', and then check if it equals x['Indi'] in the same row.
Alternatively (|), allow rows from x['Indi'] that equal 'Normal' (Series.eq).


We select from x based on this condition, cutting out all 'False' rows, and apply df.groupby to get groupby.sum for column 'Amt'.

Intermediates
After merge, before boolean indexing:
    Acc       Indi indi_val  Amt
0     1     With E     Val1   10 # < will be `False` (excluded), not 'With E'
1     1     With E     val2   20
2     1     With E    Val_E    5 # < will be `True` (included), not 'With E'
3     1     With E   Val1_E    5
4     1     With E     Val1   22
5     1     With E     Val3   38
6     1  Without E     Val1   10
7     1  Without E     val2   20
8     1  Without E    Val_E    5
9     1  Without E   Val1_E    5
10    1  Without E     Val1   22
11    1  Without E     Val3   38
12    2     With E     val2   15
13    2     With E   val2_E   25
14    2     With E  val22_E   22
15    2     With E   val2_A   23
16    2     With E   val2_V   24
17    2  Without E     val2   15
18    2  Without E   val2_E   25
19    2  Without E  val22_E   22
20    2  Without E   val2_A   23
21    2  Without E   val2_V   24
22    3     Normal    Val_E   56 # < will be `True` (included), 'Normal' always OK
23    3     Normal    Val_A   67
24    3     Normal      Val   45
25    3     Normal     Val2   87
26    4     Normal     val7   88

After boolean indexing, and before groupby:
    Acc       Indi indi_val  Amt
2     1     With E    Val_E    5
3     1     With E   Val1_E    5
6     1  Without E     Val1   10
7     1  Without E     val2   20
10    1  Without E     Val1   22
11    1  Without E     Val3   38
13    2     With E   val2_E   25
14    2     With E  val22_E   22
17    2  Without E     val2   15
20    2  Without E   val2_A   23
21    2  Without E   val2_V   24
22    3     Normal    Val_E   56
23    3     Normal    Val_A   67
24    3     Normal      Val   45
25    3     Normal     Val2   87
26    4     Normal     val7   88


You could add another column to df1 to indicate whether the indi_val includes "E" or another letter or no letter using the apply() method for your function and then use groupby to see how many of each type are associated with each Acc number.
#create function check_val
def check_val(indi_val):
if "_E" in indi_val:
    return ("With E")
if "_A" in indi_val:
    return("Without E")
if "_V" in indi_val:
    return("Without E")
if "_" not in indi_val:
    return ("Normal")
else:
    return ("Other")

#apply check_val function to your dataframe, create column Check_Val
df1["Check_Val"] = df1.apply(lambda x: check_val(x['indi_val']), axis=1)
display(df1)

Out

Acc |indi_val |Amt|Check_Val
|1  |Val1     |10 |Normal
|1  |Val2     |20 |Normal
|1  |Val_E    |5  |With E
|1  |Val1_E   |5  |With E
|1  |Val1     |22 |Normal
|1  |Val3     |38 |Normal
|2  |Val2     |15 |Normal
|2  |val2_E   |25 |With E
|2  |val22_E  |22 |With E
|2  |val2_A   |23 |Without E
|2  |val2_V   |24 |Without E
|3  |Val_E    |56 |With E
|3  |Val_A    |67 |Without E
|3  |Val      |45 |Normal
|3  |Val2     |87 |Normal
|4  |val7     |88 |Normal

#use groupby to get Amt totals of Check_Val per Acc
totals = df1.groupby(['Acc', 'Check_Val'])['Amt'].sum()
print(totals)

Out

Acc  Check_Val
1    Normal        90
     With E        10
2    Normal        15
     With E        47
     Without E     47
3    Normal       132
     With E        56
     Without E     67
4    Normal        88
Name: Amt, dtype: int64

